# Returning Functions objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, function

I have one problem I want to call a function and use the value I get from that function, here is the code of my function

```
-(double)CellWidth{
double width;


if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
    NSLog(@"Device is now in Portrait Mode");
    width = 153.6;
}
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    NSLog(@"Device is now in LandscapeLeft Mode ");
    width = 204.6;
}

return width;
}
```

that function is in Class1.m but I also declared in Class1.h like this 
    -(double)CellWidth;

now I want to use it in Class2

code in Class2.h

```
 #import "Class1.h"
 @interface ...
 {
 Class1 *class1;
 }
 @property (nonatomic,release) Class1 *class1;
```

Class2.m

I want to use this

```
self.TableView.rowHeight = [class1 CellWidth];
```

But the CellWidth is not getting called and I am not receiving the width.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing `UIInterfaceOrientation` to `CellWidth`?

Comment: "is not even calling the _function_" Here, _function_ is the object, the class or the method? Try using better names and explaining what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Is it possible you've not actually created an instance of `Function`, meaning that the runtime variable `function` is `nil`?

Comment: Calling a class 'Function' is pretty disturbing IMHO...

Comment: Have a look at the `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait` macro... `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) ? 153.6 : 204.6;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing in a parameter.

You should have something like this:

```
[self setClass1:[[[Class1 alloc] init] autorelease]];

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

//This
[[self horizontalTableView] setRowHeight:[class1 CellWidth:orientation]];
```

The reason your current implementation isn't calling that function is because you aren't telling it to call that function. You're telling it to call `[function CellWidth]` not `[function CellWidth:orientation]`

Based upon your feedback, you actually seem to want something more like this:

```
-(double)CellWidth {
    double width = 0;

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"PORTRAIT");
        width = 153.6;
    } else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
                orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"LANDSCAPE");
        width = 204.6;
    }

    return width;

}
```

then in your implementation, in Class2.m:

```
[self setClass1:[[[Function alloc] init] autorelease]];

//This
[[self horizontalTableView] setRowHeight:[class1 CellWidth]];
```

To make this even clearer, I am going to try and clean up this...

CoolCellInfo.h

```
@interface CoolCellInfo : NSObject {

}

-(double)cellWidth;

@end
```

CoolCellInfo.m

```
@implementation CoolCellInfo

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {

    }

    return self;
}

-(double)cellWidth {
    double width = 0;

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"PORTRAIT");
        width = 153.6;
    } else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
                orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"LANDSCAPE");
        width = 204.6;
    }

    return width;
}

@end
```

CoolCellUser.h

```
#import "CoolCellInfo.h"

@interface CoolCellUser : NSObject {
    CoolCellInfo *cellInfo;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CoolCellInfo *cellInfo;

@end;
```

CoolCellUser.m

```
@implementation CoolCellUser
@synthesize cellInfo;

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
         double width = [[self cellInfo] cellWidth];

         NSLog(@"Omg cell width = %f", width);
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark Lazy Loader
-(CoolCellInfo *)cellInfo {
    if(cellInfo == nil) {
        [self setCellInfo:[[[CoolCellInfo alloc] init] autorelease]];
    }

    return cellInfo;
}

@end
```

Comment: but I want to see in which orientation is the device inside cellwidth. how do i do that inside cellwidth? and i tried sending the orientation and still not calling the  cellwidth. thanks

Comment: You want a different structure for your function then. To check orientation, use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`. Also make sure that you are instantiating your variable, otherwise it is nil and this function will never be called.

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't using any instance variables in Class1, you should probably implement `CellWidth` as a [class factory method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW36) defined using `+` rather than `-`.

Now you don't need to add it as a property in Class2, but you can call it directly using the class name: `[Class1 CellWidth]`.

Comment: Agreed that if it will be the same across all Class1's, then it should be a class method rather than an instance method